# How can I rewrite history so that all files, except the ones I already moved, are in a subdirectory?

Tags: git, history, mv, git-filter-branch

I have a project under `git`. One day I moved all project files from current directory to `foo/bar/` under the project. I did it using `git mv`. Then I added some more files and did some changes to already existing files.

As a result, now when I look at the history of `foo/bar/file.c`, I can only see changes that I did after I moved the file.

I tried to fix this in various ways (`filter-branch` with subdirectory filter, etc), but nothing helped, so I am pretty stacked here. I'll appreciate any help that you can give me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 102):

**To rewrite the history with the files moved:**

If you want the project's history to look as though all files have always been in the directory `foo/bar`, then you need to do a little surgery. Use `git filter-branch` with the "tree filter" to rewrite the commits so that anywhere `foo/bar` doesn't exist, it is created and all files are moved to it:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --tree-filter '
if [ ! -e foo/bar ]; then
    mkdir -p foo/bar
    git ls-tree --name-only $GIT_COMMIT | xargs -I files mv files foo/bar
fi'
```

Now the history will be recorded as if all files were *always* located in `foo/bar`.

**To see the history of a moved file:**

If you just want to see the history of a file that has been moved or renamed at some point in the past, then simply use the `--follow` option to `git log`:

```
git log --follow foo/bar/file.c
```

Comment: @Alexander: You may want to try putting the one-liner (everything in the single quotes) in an actual script, with a bash shebang line. I think `filter-branch` is probably trying to run this in `sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: I made some progress. It seems that double brackets in if statement were causing this error. Single brackets work better, it still doesn't work though. The problem is that before I moved everything to foo/bar/ I had directory named foo with some content in the project. So now it complains "cannot move `foo' to a subdirectory of itself, `foo/bar/foo'".

Comment: @Alexander: You'll just need to adjust the script accordingly. Something like: `if [[ ! -e foo/bar ]]; then mkdir -p foo/bar; git ls-tree --name-only $GIT_COMMIT | grep -v ^foo$ | xargs -I files mv files foo/bar; fi` That uses grep to filter out `foo` from the list of files to be moved. Note that I'm also assuming that the `bar` subdirectory never existed until you moved everything under it. If that isn't the case, then you'll need to account for that in the script as well.

Comment: This works great except for the case when the repo originally contains submodules. The submodule path won't be updated. I'm assuming I can just remove the submodule and re-add it under the new path and add a commit, but that's not quite as elegant. Anything my Googling missed?

Comment: Using `[[` caused a problem for me, as there is no such command (it is a shell bulitin), using `[` and `]` solves the problem.

Comment: This seems to work, however, file that are deleted stick around in the rewritten repository.

Comment: Can this easily be undone if you are unhappy with the results after doing it on a large repo?

Comment: @TTT yes, it can be easily undone. `git filter-branch` will keep copies of the original branches under refs/original. So while on branch foo, you can do something like `git reset --hard original/foo` to put things back the way they were.

Answer (score 7):

To wrap things up here's a short summary of what I did. The command that worked for me was:

```
if [ ! -e foo/bar ]; then mkdir -p foo/bar; git ls-tree --name-only $GIT_COMMIT | grep -v ^foo$ | xargs -I files mv files foo/bar || echo ""; fi
```

The echo command that I added at the end ensured that even when mv fails entire command will continue running. It didn't move contents of foo/bar/foo, but I can live with that.

Thanks a lot to [Dan Moulding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4042965/53897) (!!!) and Jefromi for the help.

Comment: Using `|| true` instead of `|| echo ""` is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Install git-filter-repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/
```

Add the git-filter-repo executable to your $PATH (see [INSTALL.MD](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) for other options):

```
# this is just an example, you probably want to edit bashrc,
# or add a symlink to ~/bin or /usr/local/bin
PATH=$PATH:${PWD}/git-filter-repo
```

Now `cd` to the git repo that you want to modify, and run:

```
git filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter foo/bar
```