# Git submodule from subdirectory?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Let's say I have two git repos. RepoA is a common repo that should be shared among other projects. ReopB is some project that needs to access something in RepoA.

**RepoA**

```
https://.../RepoA
    /Something
    /Source
        /Project1
        /Project2
        ...
        /ProjectN
```

**RepoB**

```
https://.../RepoB
    /SomethingElse
    /Source
        /MainProject
        /RepoA
            /Project1  #Submodule of RepoA at /Source/Project1
```

Using the illustration above, you can see what I am trying to do is configure a submodule that is not the root of RepoA, but a specific path within the repo. In this case, I want to map RepoB/Source/RepoA/Project1 to RepoA/Source/Project1.

I've done some research and it seems that it is not straightforward, or perhaps not possible to do this. I hope I'm wrong!

We're moving from SVN to GIT and in SVN we were using Externals to accomplish this with ease.

**Note**

I am also open to restructuring RepoA. But I want to keep the main structure in place. For instance, if I can somehow branch each Project within RepoA/Source/...but I don't want this to get complex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge git repository in subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426247/merge-git-repository-in-subdirectory)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426247/merge-git-repository-in-subdirectory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered splitting up the 'Projects' in RepoA such that they are separate repos? You could do this by using [git subtree split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475). Then you include the Project1 repo as submodules in both RepoA and RepoB.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I'll have to do. I was hoping to NOT have to do that. Will look into it - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way out I get for this issue is to split into branches each directory that is expected to create a submodule from it. In your example, we create a branch named "branch-Project1" and put all the contents of the directory `Project1` in this new branch.

Then, on RepoB we run

```bash
git submodule add -b branch-Project1 https://github.com/<user-name>/RepoA path/to/submodule
```

This will create a submdule located at `path/to/submodule` in RepoB.