# How can combine different repositories in gitHub?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, github, repository

I have a different repositories:

- A- Java Spring repository
- B- React repository

Can ı combine this repositories in one repository like this:

- Java Spring Folder
- React Folder

I searched on the internet and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: yes, you can, like you said, you have two folders

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- create a third repository and reference the first two [as submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)
- or [import commits of one repository into the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62104992/6309) (or import both into a new one), using [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)