# Keep commits history after a 'git merge'

Tags: git, github, merge, git-branch

When I work on two different features (on two different branches created from the *master*) it is quite annoying that I will not have the commit history when I proceed with merging.

I'll explain better. When I finish work on *Branch-A*, I merge it into *master*. And that's fine, if I `git log` I see all the commits I made on *Branch-A*.

**Instead**, when I finish work on *Branch-B* and I try to merge it to *master* (after that *Branch-A* has been already merged), I have to specify a commit message for the merging (while for the first branch I have not been asked anything).
And after the merging to *master*, if I type `git log`, I cannot see the commits of the *Branch-B* in the history of my *master* branch

Let's say I have

```
**Branch A**

commit 09b2unfas9d781n2e
    Add more stuff

commit 8uj8masd89jas898a
    Add stuff

**Branch B**

commit 09b2unfas9d781n2e
    Add feature setting

commit 8uj8masd89jas898a
    Add feature
```

I finish having

```
**Master**

commit 6hf6h8hd871udjkdn
Merge: 09b2un 34osd6
    Merge branch 'Branch-B' into master

commit 09b2unfas9d781n2e
    Add more stuff

commit 8uj8masd89jas898a
    Add stuff

commit 34osd62dhc91123j8
    I'm a previous commit from 'master'.
    The last one before branching...
```

while **I would like to obtain** something like:

```
**Master**

commit 09b2unfas9d781n2e
    Add feature setting

commit 8uj8masd89jas898a
    Add feature

commit 09b2unfas9d781n2e
    Add more stuff

commit 8uj8masd89jas898a
    Add stuff

commit 34osd62dhc91123j8
    I'm a previous commit from 'master'.
    The last one before branching...
```

... that would reflect more exactly the history of the performed commits.

I don't get why I can keep the history from just one of the two branches.

How can I keep everything clear without those *merge* commits that hide/omit the real history of the merged commits?

Answer (score 58):

It looks like the first merge was a fast-forward, and the second one was a three-way merge.

**Explanation**

Git has two versions of merge: *fast-forward* and *three-way*. (There are other versions, but that is not what happened here.) The default behavior is to do a fast-forward merge when possible, and otherwise do a three-way merge.

A *fast-forward* merge can take place when the commit that is being merged has the current position of the branch in its history (you can force this behavior with the option `--ff-only`, which will cause the merge to fail when fast-forward is impossible). For example:

```
A - B - C - D <-master
             \
              E - F - G <- branch-a
```

Executing `git merge` (with default settings) will result in

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G <- branch-a <-master
```

You will also not get a chance to edit the merge commit because there is none.

A *three-way* merge when your other branch diverges from `master` (not just ahead):

```
A - B - C - D  - E - F - G <-master
                  \
                   E1 - E2 <- branch-b
```

In this case, Git cannot just move the pointer of master from `G` to `E2` because that will get rid of the changes that were made in `F` and `G`. When a three-way merge happens, it creates a commit that has two parents, and also has a commit message. Now, `master` can be moved to this commit. (Notice that in this situation, `master` and `branch-b` do NOT point to the same commit.

```
A - B - C - D  - E - F - G - H <-master
                  \       /
                   E1 - E2 <- branch-b
```

If you want to have a linear history then you need to use rebase, but be forewarned that if anybody else has seen your branch commits this may lead to issues that are beyond the scope of this answer. Using rebase will involve two steps, rebasing and then fast-forward merge. So, instead of merging you first execute the following while on **branch-b**, `git rebase master`. This creates new commits that are copies of the old commits, i.e., the same change-set, author information and message, but new committer information and parent history. (I call the commits E1' and E2' in the illustration to indicate that they are just copies.) The old commits will exist until they are garbage collected, but will not be reachable unless you look at the reflog.)

```
A - B - C - D  - E - F - G <-master
                  \       \
                   E1 - E2 \ 
                            E1' - E2' <- branch-b
```

Executing `git checkout master; git merge --ff-only branch-b` will now fast-forward your changes into master, thereby giving you a linear history.

```
A - B - C - D  - E - F - G - E1' -E2' <-master <- branch-b
```

Comment: I need merge `master` to `branch-b` when I have changes in both. How I can rewrite `branch-b` like it was started from commit `G`, not `E`? But keep commit history of `branch-b` and commit changes to `branch-b` that are conflicts. Assuming I'm only one who knows about `branch-b`.

Comment: Nvm it's exact `git rebase master`.

Answer (score 11):

Use [`rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) instead of `merge`. From the [tutorial](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing):

> If you examine the log of a rebased branch, it looks like a linear
>   history: it appears that all the work happened in series, even when it
>   originally happened in parallel.

I imagine that the changes from your `Branch-B` cannot be merged using **fast-forward** merging into the `master`. In such cases a [**three-way-merge**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) is done:

> Instead of just moving the branch pointer forward, Git creates a new
>   snapshot that results from this three-way merge and automatically
>   creates a new commit that points to it. This is referred to as a merge
>   commit, and is special in that it has more than one parent.

I would always rebase my commits before commiting them into the `master` to keep the linear history.

Comment: I just got an upvote and I must say: after 3 years, I **don't** rebase with master anymore before merging!

Comment: Why? Quite curious, since I see a general tendency going that direction...  Maybe not to loose info about branches? Don't those merge commits annoy you on readability?

Comment: I cannot say why, but rebases change the history of git and **may** be confusing for others! :)

Comment: If you rebase **only** your local working branch, before merging it to master, then there's no confusion - since no one is using your local branch. Not even you, after it's once happily joined the master.

Comment: @Kamafeather you were right! Now in 2022 I'm forced to always rebase. And my argument about rebases being confusing was wrong all the way!

Comment: ❤️ glad it helped evolving your workflow! It daily helps mine, in decluttering and retaining metadata & diffs for debugging git history. – Although at times it requires more work or is tricky with the rewriting of history. IMHO, It's worth the hassle; but your argument wasn't wrong, I understand my git rebase workflow *may* be confusing (iirc as newbie I couldn't grasp rebasing). To beginners I'd suggest to stick with `merge` and to *never* pick commits from my WIP branches (that… I backup onto `origin`, prefixed as `kama/WIP/feature-5`, waiting to yell at anybody that touches them ).

Comment: Lately I also abuse rebasing to reorder/squash/remove/fix previous commits and clean up even more; I like the anarchist power of `rebase` in spite of the more conformist `merge`!  ✊

Comment: When I merged ~5 commits from feature branch into main, I noticed the timeline was not linear when I would like that to happen. Now I can clearly see rebasing's powerful usage compared to merge in this case. 