# git: copy (cherry-pick) history of one repository into a directory of another

Tags: git

I have two repos.  First repo (let's call it A) started a while ago; second repo (B) started very recently.  Now we're thinking we would rather have just made B a subdirectory of A.  So I'd like to do that, but keep B's commit history.

- I want the full commit history.  i.e. I don't want to just squash B's history into one patch and drop that as a new commit in A.
- I do not care to preserve the exact SHA1s of B (I understand that that's probably impossible).
- I do not care to preserve the timestamps of B's commits (though that would be nice to have).
- I do not care to preserve authorship.
- I just want to preserve the diffs/patches of each of B's commits.
- I don't care to preserve any notion of two separate repositories.  In fact, I want there only to be A going forward.
- I don't need B to be a git submodule of A, with its own `.git` dir or anything like that.

At the end of whatever operations are done, I want three criteria satisfied:

1. The files and directories as seen at the `HEAD` of B are seen in a subdirectory of A i.e. `/path/to/repoB/somefile.js` is found at `/path/to/repoA/B/somefile.js`
2. All the commit messages of B are seen, in order, at the chronological end of the commits of A
3. The diffs of each commit are available (viewable by `git log`, etc.)

Some examples may clarify what I intend:

1. In repo B, commit 1 is to add `file.txt`
2. commit 2 is to edit `file.txt`
3. So in repo A, I want two new commits:
4. repo A commit 98: add `B/file.txt`
5. repo A commit 99: edit `B/file.txt`

---

EDIT:

[Merge git repository in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426247) has been proposed as a duplicate of my question.  I'll admit that it is extremely close to what I'm asking, and has several fine answers.  I tried the `subtree` answer there, as well as the `rebase --onto` answer.  Both were very close, but were unsatisfactory: `subtree` didn't allow `git log` to see the history across the repository histories without referring to `path/to/file/without/repo-subdir` (where I moved B into `repo-subdir`); and `rebase --onto` didn't make B's history visible from A's `HEAD`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge git repository in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426247/merge-git-repository-in-subdirectory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+make+one+repository+subdirectory+another

Comment: In particular, see the `git subtree` answer to phd's suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing.  Thanks to `atrus` from `#git` in Freenode (IRC) for steering me in the right direction.

1. **In repo B**, make a new branch: `git checkout -b indir`
2. In repo B, `mkdir b-subdir`, where `b-subdir` is the dir I intend for B to end up in the dir tree of A.
3. In repo B, `git mv [...] b-subdir` to move everything (except `.git/` and `b-subdir/` itself) into `b-subdir`.
4. Commit that move to repo B.
5. Push to origin (`push -u origin HEAD`).
6. **In repo A**: `git remote add repo-b ssh://......../repo-b.git`
7. `git fetch repo-b`
8. `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories repo-b/indir`

This allows me to see the full history of arbitrary files that came from repo B (using the `--follow` switch of `git log`) *without* needing to strip off the `b-subdir/` prefix from the filepath.  With `git subtree`, you only see the file's history in B if you strip that off (and you see the history in A if you don't).