# How to add a git repo as folder into another git repo as a folder?

Tags: git

I want to add the git repo https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib.git tag v0.7.7 with all history as a folder cpphttp_lib to my another git repo called common.git. Any iea on how to do this ?, git-filter-repo can be used somehow to achieve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge git repository in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426247/merge-git-repository-in-subdirectory)

Comment: [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: [`git subtree`](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt)

Comment: You should also consider using [a real dependency manager](https://github.com/LoopPerfect/buckaroo/wiki). Git is a poor substitute.

Answer (score 0):

I chose to use git subtree command to solve issue mentioned in the question above. I like the git subtree concept and it works for my use case.