# Git merge remotes into a subfolder

Tags: git

I am trying to create a monorepo from multiple existing repos. I have created a project with its own .git, README.md, ... and a /packages folder, where I want to place the merged repos as subfolders. But after I do this

```
cd packages
git remote add existing-1 git@...
git fetch --all
git merge existing-1/master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

I get merge conflicts (README.md etc), because git wants to merge the repo into root, not /packages. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I can't close the question since it is answered already. I found git-subtree to be the best solution. I just need to do

```
git subtree add -P packages/existing-1 git@... master
```

where git@... is the remote URL. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684526/4125622

Comment: This looks like a good find. I'll keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to do this is to copy all the files from the old repo into the new repo and make one very large commit.

If you insist on maintain histories, I can think of two ways:

1. Start a clean repo and fetch the old repo like you are already doing. Then `git mv` the files into the new subfolder structure that you want. Rinse and repeat for each of the projects you want to add to the new repo. Then finally add the scafolding for your monorepo.
2. In the old repo, `git mv` the files to the directory structure you want. Then merge into the new repo similar to what you are already doing.

Comment: Thanks, if I wanted to do it manually, I would do it that way. See my answer for a shortcut