# Git: Can I put all contents in a sub folder and still have history

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to move/rename files in git and maintain their history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314652/is-it-possible-to-move-rename-files-in-git-and-maintain-their-history)

I am a previous subversion user, not sure how git could help me in following situation.

I have a git repository where my project was contained having multiple dirs, I've been making several commits over this structure

Now I need to make structure changes, so that I move all folders/files at root to a new folder, and I still want to keep commit history of files.

so for example in my repo I currently have a structure like this

```
src
res
xml
file.txt
.gitignore
```

I want all of them to be moved in a folder called common, so that I have following structure at the root of repo

```
common
.gitignore
```

Is it possible , if so how ?

Thank you

Comment: Don't think its duplicate of the reference you gave, the questioner there already seems to know what I want to know. hence the answers there are based on that assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use commands like this

```
mkdir common
git mv src res xml file.txt common
```

This moves the files and you can still see the history with `git log --follow common/file.txt`.  If you'd rather rewrite history, check out [How can I rewrite history so that all files, except the ones I already moved, are in a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042816/how-can-i-rewrite-history-so-that-all-files-are-in-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 4):

```
mkdir common
git mv src res xml file.txt common
git commit
```

Comment: This won't maintain the history for these files. You would need to `git log --follow` to see the history.

Comment: Yes, it will. Or rather it can't because git does not track per-file history. It always tracks the history of the whole repository.