# How can I rewrite git history so that all files are in a parent directory?

Tags: git

In git, I would like to take the history entries for `books/trunk` and move them to `books`.  What I need is something that's an inverse of posts like these:

[How can I rewrite history so that all files are in a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042816/how-can-i-rewrite-history-so-that-all-files-are-in-a-subdirectory)

For the curious, the motivation for this question is that I'm using svnadmin to merge a couple svn repos and convert them to git.  The answer could also be used to rewrite old svn history once you've converted to git.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Linux bash:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter \
  'test -d books/trunk && mv books/trunk/* books/trunk/.[^.]* ./books || echo "Nothing to do"' \
  HEAD
```

Note that despite the exclusion of .., you will still get errors about being unable to move ./.. -- just ignore those.  (I'd welcome someone cleaning that up, but please test it first).